# How to output data from MySQL db into clickable links? Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, url, href

How do I convert the data coming from mysql database (website_url) into clickable links?

```
<?php   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sports";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<table>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

       echo "<tr>";
                       echo "<td>" . $row  ['website_url'] .     "</td>"; 
       echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } 
 } 
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

How do I make the URLs which are received from the database through this piece of code as clickable links?

```
 echo "<td>" .$row['website_url']. "</td>";
```

The data received from the database would be like:

- https://www.google.com/ 
   https://www.facebook.com/ 
   etc..

Please help!

Comment: Maybe `<a href='website-url'>website-url</a>` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's standard HTML, e.g.:

```
$url = $row  ['website_url'];
echo "<td><a href='" . $url . "'>" . $url . "</a></td>";
```

You need to wrap links into `a` tags. Maybe you should start with a basic HTML tutorial to learn these things :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much!

I was working on  this for hours and I knew I was overlooking something very simple..

I forgot to remove the inner quotation marks of the column tags, I was doing this..

```
$url = $row  ['website_url'];
echo "<td> " <a href='" . $url . "'>" . $url . "</a> " </td>";
```

Correct code.. Without the inner quotation marks < td>"......"< /td >

```
 $url = $row  ['website_url'];
 echo "<td> <a href='" . $url . "'>" . $url . "</a> </td>";
```

Comment: Your example should throw a syntax error, why you haven't sad that? And, next time, it would be great, if you would post your code as it :)